# Perl: insert a "\n" every 70 characters

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have the following problem. I have a long string (1 thousand characters, more or less) and I am required to insert a "\n" every 70 characters. My idea was

```
my $finalstr;
    for($i=0; $i<=length($input)+1; $i=$i+70){
    $finalstr.=$finalstr.substr($input,$i,3)."\n";
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.The problem is that I don't know how to use regex in this case because the number of characters in `$input` could be not a multiple of 70.

Comment: `s/.{70}/$&\n/g;` should still work. Anything at the end which is less than 70 characters long will obviously not require any modification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```
$finalstr =~ s/(.{70})/$1\n/gs;
```

Expression `(.{70})` captures 70 characters, and then `$1\n` substitutes with the captured part followed by a new line. Modifier `g` makes the search global (each and every match is replaced).

Note: If you string does not contain embedded new lines, you can remove the final `s`.

Example (with 4 characters instead of 70):

```
$ perl -we 'my $finalstr = "123456789"; $finalstr =~ s/(.{4})/$1\n/gs; print "$finalstr\n";'
1234
5678
9
$
```

---

**Edit**

As commented by [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami), an alternative solution would be:

```
$finalstr =~ s/.{70}\K/\n/g;
```

Rationale:

- the `\K` character class indicates that what is left of it should not be suppressed; hence no capturing is needed (this is more efficient than capturing and replacing)
- removing the `s` modifier avoids counting in new lines as characters when matching; thus, if a new line is embedded in the string, the next line will accept 70 characters instead of just the remainder of the previous line.

Comment: Thank you GMB. This works. However I would like to ask to you some more clarification, whether possible.This regular expression means: "substitute, when find 70 characters, the previous regular expression (i.e the 70 character) plus a \n." Is that correct?

Comment: @ele: yes that is correct. I added a few explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you what was the problem with my idea? Because it doesn't seem to "concatenate" what I ask.

Comment: @ikegami: thanks for your valuable suggestions, I added them to my answer.

Comment: @ele: see the good response by Holli about what was wrong with your initial solution.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems: In the call to `substr` you specify a value of 3. That obviously should be 70. Then you are concatenating to the target string *twice*, first by using `.=` and then by repeating the `$finalstr`. You need to use either one, not both.

Correcting that gives you

```
for($i=0; $i<=length($input)+1; $i=$i+70){
    $finalstr .= substr($input,$i,70)."\n";
}
```

Which works as you intended. `substr` can also act as an `lvalue` though, so if you don't mind the `$input` being altered you can use that form:

```
for($i=70; $i<=length($input)+1; $i=$i+71){
    substr($input,$i,0) = "\n"; 
}
```